# How to forbid cyclic edge connections between vertexes on mxgraph (acyclic graph)

Tags: javascript, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, mxgraph

I have created a custom editor using [mxGraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph).In my editor, the user should be able to create an `acyclic graph`. When the user `will try to make a cycle in the graph`, a popup should appear informing the user that `cycles are not permitted` in the graph and rollback should take place.

The `mxGraph` object has the property `multigraph (boolean)` which specifies if the graph should allow multiple connections between the same pair of vertices and has a similar behaviour with the one I want described above.

I have searched the mxGraph object's code for any similar property declaring that the graph should be acyclic but have not found anything so far. I maybe could implement my own custom logic to make the graph acyclic but I should each and every time that I would connect a pair of vertexes traverse the belonging tree of the targeted vertex to check if a cycle will be created which would be very expensive/time-consuming since the graph may includes thousands of vertexes and edges so I am looking for a simple way / out of the box way (if any exists) to achieve it.

**Example - Acyclic graph (OK)**

[image]

**Example - Cyclic graph (Not OK - should not be allowed)**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same problem and tried to solve it, but it may not be the best solution.Our solution as below:

1. We used  DFS algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search
2. Instead of validating the entire DAG graph, we bind the validation function to the mxCell connectivity event. This improves efficiency and also allows the user to get real-time response.

Below are sample codes:

```
// validation function.Need to set id for each cell.
this.graph.connectionHandler.validateConnection = (source, target) => {
    const childrenNodes = [];
    this.deepGetChildren(target, childrenNodes)
    //check the children ids 
    if (childrenNodes.indexOf(source.id) > -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
/**
* Recursive function
* get all child nodes of cell by cell
*/
deepGetChildren(cell, ids) {
    //if the cell is the end node, or the cell have no edge,just put
    if (cell.type === 'end' || cell.edges === undefined) {
        if (ids.indexOf(cell.id) === -1) {
            ids.push(cell.id)
        }
    } else {
        if (cell.edges !== null && cell.edges.length > 0) {
            for (const item of cell.edges) {
                //Only need to calculate the output connection
                if (item.target !== null&&item.target.id !== cell.id&&ids.indexOf(item.target.id) === -1) {
                       this.deepGetChildrens(item.target, ids)
                }
        } else {
            if (ids.indexOf(item.target.id) === -1) {
                ids.push(item.target.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, well as we have discussed before I am managing this through a backend solution but in the future I might use your customization in case I need an extra layer check, so +1 for now and I will accept the answer when I will try it or anybody else from the community finds it helpful :)

Comment: Thanks, hope it will be helpful to others. :)